# Angular 2 custom transition animation (non CSS based)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, angular

I'm relatively new to Angular2, but it seems it has a thorough method of creating animations: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#example-transitioning-between-states

It seems you can do any CSS3 transition animation you can think of, but I was wondering if it is also possible to use some custom DOM manipulation instead. For example, instead of a CSS transition I would like to be able to define something like the text random shuffle effect, e.g. http://git.blivesta.com/chaffle/

Is this possible or am I limited to only CSS3 transitions in Angular2 animations?